# Error al emplear cursor en datos de una variable en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

He creado un procedimiento almacenado en el cual consulto los datos de una tabla y los inserto en una tabla temporal.

```
DECLARE @credito TABLE
        (
            [id_credito] [numeric](18, 0)
        );
        INSERT INTO 
            @credito 
        SELECT 
            [id_credito]
        FROM 
            credito
            WHERE id_credito > 1
```

Mi procedimiento funciona perfecto, he probado y se insertan todos los valores.

Ahora, pretendo pasar los registros existentes en la tabla `@crédito` en base al `id_credito` uno a uno a otro procedimiento almacenado, para que se ejecute otra operación.

Para esto empleo un cursor para que los recorra fila a fila.

```
DECLARE @IdCredito numeric(18,0)

            DECLARE registro_cursor CURSOR FOR select [id_credito] from @credito
            OPEN registro_cursor

            FETCH NEXT FROM registro_cursor INTO @IdCredito

            BEGIN       
                EXEC [Reporte].[Calcular_diasvencidos]@IdCredito
                FETCH NEXT FROM registro_cursor INTO @IdCredito
            END
            CLOSE registro_cursor;
            DEALLOCATE registro_cursor;
```

Lo que sucede es que al ejecutar el procedimiento completo, solo me esta sucediendo con el primer registro y no se a que se debe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace falta comprobar que la lectura del registro fue correcta con la variable @@fetch_status, por ese motivo es que solo toma el primer registro.

```
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
```

Tu código debería estar así:

```
        DECLARE @IdCredito numeric(18,0)

        DECLARE registro_cursor CURSOR FOR select [id_credito] from @credito
        OPEN registro_cursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM registro_cursor INTO @IdCredito
        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN       
            EXEC [Reporte].[Calcular_diasvencidos]@IdCredito
            FETCH NEXT FROM registro_cursor INTO @IdCredito
        END
        CLOSE registro_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE registro_cursor;
```